# renderizar/redireccionar en vue 2

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

estoy intentando renderizar otro componente/pag con vue 2 pero no lo consigo aqui mi codigo:

main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import App from './App.vue'
import VueSweetalert2 from 'vue-sweetalert2'
import 'sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.min.css'
import Home from './components/Home.vue'
const options = {
  confirmButtonColor: '#FF0000',
  cancelButtonColor: '#ff7674',
};
Vue.use(VueSweetalert2, options);
Vue.use(VueRouter);
const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [{
    path: '/home',
    component: Home,
  }]
});
new Vue({
  router,
  render: (h) => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```

Boton en componente login:

```
methods: {
    async login() {
      try {
        const response = await axios.post("url del api", {
          username: this.username,
          password: this.password,
        });
        console.log(response.status)
        if (response.status == 200) {
          this.$router.push('/home');
        }
      } catch (error) {
        this.$swal('Username or password incorrect!!!');
      }
```

La url cambia una vez que el login es correcto a localhost:5273/home pero no renderiza el componente home sino que se queda en el login....que estoy haciendo mal? Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Debe indicar el path porque es lo que usa, no literal string path.

```
  routes: [{
    path: '/home',
    component: Home,
  }]
```

/*vue-router 2.x*/

```
this.$router.push({ path: '/home' })
```